# Issues in executing gradle task through terminal in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, gradlew

I am writing a simple gradle task in my project level `build.gradle`. The code is pretty simple.

```
task compile {
    doLast {
        println 'compiling source'
    }
}
```

When I try to execute the task from Gradle-> Gradle projects in the right hand panel, it compiles and prints the result.

But, when I go to the Terminal in Android studio and type

```
./gradlew -q compile
```

it shows error message

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'xx'
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
```

When in the Terminal I write other gradle commands, it displays perfect, like

./gradlew -h
./gradlew -v

Somehow, it does not execute the gradle task.

*** EDIT ***
My project level build.gradle uses

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
```

What is that I am doing wrong? Any suggestion will b very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you would want to make a task then let that task `finalize` the `compileJava` task.

```
task myTask {
    println "doing stuff"
}
project.tasks.findByName('compileJava').finalizedBy myTask
```

We can now see the task executing in the build

```
$ gradle -q clean build
doing stuff
```